# Differentiating input and output color in Python in terminal

Tags: python-2.7, terminal

In review a particular session in python (that I execute via the terminal) I'd like to more easily differentiate between what i've typed in and what is returned after execution. Is there a way to change the colors of these?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python).  It's the only feasible way I see it doing what you're asking for.  I don't think the terminal can decipher on its own what user input is.